# Windows could not start the SQL Server on local computer error 1067

Tags: sql-server

The SQL Server 2019 service doesn't start on my PC.

The error shows:

> Windows could not start the SQL Server on local computer (error 1067)

I checked the event log, but there is no useful information in it.
I also tried command line and PowerShell, and still no direct error.

Comment: Have you tried locating and inspecting the instance's `ERRORLOG` file yet? The path to this file is visible on the Startup Parameters tab ( the `-e` parameter) of the service's properties inside SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager. If this is a brand new installation of SQL Server I'd be looking at the drive you've installed it on to see if it is reporting sectors larger than 4kB.

Comment: This really helped. The ERRORLOG for the instance was located in a drive which no longer exists on my PC. I changed it and yes!